# GA report API v4, I want to update data every minute. How to update data if there is no identifier?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have some criteria for the report and I want to add them to postresql and update for example every minute.Should i have to call reporting api for the current day and overwrite all the data for the current day?

Answer (score 0):

calling reporting API every second for today's data has a little sense since Analytics [data processing lag is 24-48](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en) hours and most probably your data won't be updated with  1-sec frequency.

Also, the only convenient way to export data to own storage from API is scheduled calling reporting API for a dynamically generated date range (like last seven days) and overwriting the existing data in the storage.
You might add `ga:date` to your reported dimensions to get your report data date-wise so you'll be able to track what needs to be updated.